# NGX Cookie service returns nothing

Tags: angular, cookies, angular-universal, ngx-cookie-service

I'm using NGX Cookie Service in my AuthGuard.ts to check if a user is logged in using a cookie.
The problem is when I try to get the raw value of the cookie user the function `get` it always returns me a blank string.

However I can still create a cookie and that works fine.

I did put the cookie as a provider in my App Module and also in my child modules.

I'm Using angular 8 with Angular Universal.

Any ideas how can I fix this weird bug?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is server side or client side that you cannot access the cookies? How is the cookie created? And is it a httpOnly  cookie?

Comment: David, thanks! Forgot to remove the httpOnly option

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cookies set with `httpOnly` cannot be read from the browser (see [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#Security))

Using `httpOnly` is more secure, so I'd advise that you leave it enabled

When using angular universal, you should only try to access these cookies when the code is executed server side.