# How to get values from cookies using angular?

Tags: angular, cookies, webserver, session-cookies, angular-cookies

I have a system on the Internet that enables me to add custom applications to it through a window within this system. When you enter this window, the user session hash will be sent to the URL of the my custom application by GET method.
By default, the web server sends the following cookies when an external application link opens:

- User session hash as hash=c75b8k45y2hf5j9w6d394v98.
- Locale as locale=en.

[image]

My question, How can I get session hash value to use it in my custom page in angular?

I tried this code but it didn't work:

```
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';
constructor(private cookieService: CookieService){}
ngOnInit(): void
 {
    console.log("Hash is : ",this.cookieService.get("session_key"));
    console.log("session_key is : ", this.cookieService.get("session_key"));
    console.log("local is : ", this.cookieService.get("locale"));
 }
```

But the result in console is empty.
[image]

Comment: @SyedRafay , please could you resolve this ?

Comment: your key name is 'hash', why you try to get cookie with name 'session_key'?
try this.cookieService.get("hash"); this.cookieService.get("locale")

Comment: @Belouccio , I tried it with "hash" but not working, you can see my question after editing.

Comment: maybe you have httpOnly cookies, look this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62608566/ngx-cookie-service-returns-nothing

also you can try this lib https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-cookies

hope it helps)

Comment: i checked this in my project using console.log(document.cookie), so i see only cookies without onlyHttp and secure flags, and with same domain (localhost in my case), so maybe this problem with domain

Comment: look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8834436/how-to-get-cookies-from-a-different-domain-with-php-and-javascript

Comment: @Belouccio , I tried all this codes, but not working. How can I resolve this problem ?